# Random function returns the same number repeatedly

Tags: .net, vb.net, random

I have a really weird problem in vb.net, for some reason system.random() is not being random at all in any of my functions:

```
Public Function RandomNumber(ByVal MaxNumber As Integer, Optional ByVal MinNumber As Integer = 0) As Integer

        Dim R As System.Random = New System.Random()
        If MinNumber > MaxNumber Then
            Dim T As Integer = MinNumber
            MinNumber = MaxNumber
            MaxNumber = T
        End If
        Return R.Next(MinNumber, MaxNumber)
    End Function
```

Here is result after calling exactly 9 times

```
4
4
4
3
3
3
3
3
3
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: See also - http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Comment: [Looks random to me](http://xkcd.com/221/) :):):):)

Comment: C# != VB. Just saying.

Comment: Lost count of question like this. Please do a bit of reasearch first.....

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I always [liked this](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/) better

Comment: -1 because a search for [`[C#] random number duplicate`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BC%23%5D+random+number+duplicate) would have returned .. duplicates. Search *first*, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of how Random is implemented.  The simplest fix is to declare the following line at the Class level, not within the function.

```
 Dim R As System.Random = New System.Random()
```

The Random class uses time as a seed.  The way you're doing it declared a new Random several times per second, most likely, so Random.Next has no idea that there was a previously "random" number created already.  If you declare it at the class level, it will exist outside the scope of the funciton call, and the will "know" it's already generated a number and will be able to generatea different number.

Example here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/random